# in codeigniter2.1.4,is it mandatory pass the file's field name in do_upload function or not

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm curious to know in $this->upload->do_upload('img') field name is passing mandotory not.I have seen several example in stackoverflow where do_upload() not taking any argument as file field name.But in case of mine without field name file not uploaded.I want to know which is correct syntax?

2)How do i bypass the file upload validation when there is no file being uploaded.If there is no file(image) in the form then $this->upload->display_errors() will not be called.my  code is below

```
function add()
{
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
    {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category Name', 'required');
     if ($this->form_validation->run())
     {
        $data_to_store = array(
             'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'parent'=>'0'
         );
        $last_id=$this->admin_category_model->add_category($data_to_store);

        $config['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|GIF|JPG|PNG';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['file_name'] =$last_id.'_'.$_FILES['img']['name'];
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('img'))
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
             $config2['source_image'] = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
            $config2['new_image'] ='./uploads/thumb/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            $config2['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config2['width'] = 35;
             $config2['height'] = 35;
            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config2);
            $this->image_lib->resize(); 
            $data_to_store = array(
             'img' => $config['file_name'],
             );
           $this->admin_category_model->update_category($last_id,$data_to_store);
           $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'Record Added');
            redirect('admin_category/index');
        }
         else
        {
         $data['error']=$this->upload->display_errors();
        }

     }

    }
    $data['title']='Add Category';
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/add_category';
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/template', $data);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st) No, not necessary, by default it will take the name `userfile`.
2nd) Say for example your fieldname is `img` check like this:

```
if( $_FILES['img']['name'] != "" ){
    //your upload code here
}
```

Comment: if i use userfile instead of img then in $this->upload->do_upload() will work?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use do_upload() function without suppling the file name.

Comment: in second point i'm searching for any codeigniter syntax exists?

Comment: Nope, nothing like Im aware of.